# How can I access my admin page when I deploy a website?[for beginners]

Tags: php, html, css, content-management-system

I can code. But I'm not experienced in terms of website deployment. I want to build a website with a registration form (w/ DB). I know how to do it but I don't how it will work when I deploy it. How can I access my admin page in that case?

Comment: On your browser go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: are you using some kind of framework?

Comment: If you have install it on a server go to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x/phpmyadmin replace x with the ip of the server

Comment: Your question is not really clear for me.
 So let me try to understand, you have already programmed a registration form that takes you in case of correct authorization to an admin panel page? Or you are using some framework or CMS ? Or you mean your database admin page? If you already have it working locally then it should work online (if everything is set up correctly including for sure the database).

Comment: If it's already on the web with a domain name?

Comment: @shadi yes. how can I access my admin page when I already have a domain name for it? Ex. my admin page is like a typical CMS(WP/Drupal) admin but hard coded.

Comment: @Jackskiee something like index.html/admin

Comment: @Lööri I use Codeigniter as backend. I just want to have an admin page same as the admin page in CMS(WP/DRUPAL)

Comment: @Lööri Yes. But how can I make it secure. Or how can I restrict users hte admin page?

Comment: @Jackskiee I think SO is wrong place to ask how to make it secure. You can try to get some ideas to security from http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have install phpmyadmin on wamp or xamp e.t.c you can easy access phpmyadmin by going to

```
Http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

If you have install it on a server you have to enter the ip of the server

```
Http://192.168.1.100/phpmyadmin
```

In both cases the ip will work
Dont forget to replace the ip with your server ip

Comment: How about like the functionality of the admin page like in CMS(WP/Drupal) what is the best implementation to make the admin page? Example, is it good to do example.com/admin? What is the best way to secure it?

Answer (score 0):

The same way you access it locally. but by replacing the localhost address with your domain address.

Let's say that locally you have a login page that you access like this:

```
http://localhost/my_webiste/admin/login.php
```

Then when you upload your webiste on your own host then you can access like this:

```
http://www.my_domain.com/admin/login.php
```

Comment: How can I make my admin page secure/restricted to the other users?

Comment: @Jackskiee This is a completely new question.But as very short image you will use Sessions to make sure if the user has already logged in, otherwise you will redirect him to the login page. You have to protect all the files in the admin folders (or the files that have only admin access right). You can gain more security also by securing the functions (don't let a function run before making sure that the current user has right to run it). Additionally you must encrypt the  password in the database. And a lot more, my answer is not by any means a reference, you have to search and learn about it.